# How to fetch a product from woocommerce api based on the sku?

Tags: python, django, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I found difficulty in fetching a product from my woocommerce website to my django app based on the sku.

In the official documentation here: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product

i found a solution only for fetching the product knowing the post id(794 in the example),like:

`print(wcapi.get("products/794").json())`

Is there a way to catch the product based on the sku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

```
r=wcapi.get("products?filter[sku]='"+sku+"'").json()
```

Answer (score 7):

This also works as `filter` has been deprecated in newer versions:

```
sku="YOUR SKU HERE"
productlist=wcapi.get("products/?sku="+sku).json()
productid=productlist[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

At least as of REST API v3 SKU is included in get(params) possible values, so

```
    r = wcapi.get("products", params={'sku':sku})
```

would be the preferred method.

Comment: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#list-all-products